# Linker errors - undefined references

Tags: c++, linker

Yes, I know this has been asked a billion times before, I've checked at least 100 duplicates of this question, and still haven't found an answer.

I'm getting `undefined reference` errors to all of my `LList` functions, although it all seems to be properly defined and linked. Since my code is a bit too long to paste here, I made a pastie: **[Click](http://pastebin.com/gwwJcHh8)**

I compile my code with: `g++ driver.cpp box.cpp LList.cpp Song.cpp Album.cpp -o driver`

Comment: What part of your question do you think will help somebody to answer the question? Why do you think it's properly linked? Did you consider a SSCCE?

Comment: Well it might help other people getting into the programming scene as myself, although not very likely. I did consider a SSCCE, but I did not know how else to put forth my question.

Comment: Oops, seems I misread your comment. I've specified the type of errors, which of my classes is making them and I've linked my whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template classes and functions must be defined inline. Thats the problem. For example:

```
//box.h
#ifndef BOX_H
#define BOX_H

template <typename DataType>
struct box
{
        DataType data;
        box<DataType> *next;
        box(DataType d, box<DataType>* n)
        {
                data = d;
                next = n;
        }
};

#endif
```

And remove the .cpp file; you should do the same to the LList.h/cpp

Comment: That did the job! Thank you very much, I didn't know that.

Comment: You are welcome. And also, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

A class or function `template` is **not** a class or function and hence cannot be placed in a `.cpp` file like classes or functions. Rather, a `template` is a *blueprint* for how to make a class or function, namely a particular *instantination* of the template.

You can solve your problem in two ways:

**1** either put all the templated code in the respective header files.

**2** or instantinate the code explicitly in the `.cpp` files. For example

```
// Llist.cpp
#include Llist.hpp
#include Sonc.hpp

/* definition of members of Llist<> */

template class Llist<Song>;   // creates class Llist<Song>
```

Solution **1** always works, but has the potential for HUGE header files and exposes all (or most) implementation details to the user. Solution **2** avoids huge headers and hides implementation details, but requires that you know which instantination you actually need (often impossible, in particular for such general concepts as linked lists).

Finally, solution **3**: use the C++ standard library (`std::list`, `std::forward_list`) and don't worry.

Comment: Good explanation, but the solution 3 isn't always viable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Makes it all much clearer.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira No, but much more often than post on SO make use of it.